# Trivialization of a path of tamed almost complex structures

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra, almost-complex

I am wondering if the following result is true:

Let $(V,\omega)$ be a symplectic vector space and $\{J_t\}_{0\leq t\leq 1}$ a smooth path of almost complex structures on $V$ which are tamed by $\omega$, i.e.
$$J_t^2 = \mathbb{1}, \qquad\omega(v,J_t v) >0\quad \forall v \in V \backslash\{0\}.$$
Does there exists a path $\Phi_t \in GL(V)$ and a $\omega$-tame almost complex structure $\tilde{J}$ such that
$$ \Phi_t^* J_t = \tilde{J}, \qquad \Phi_t^*\omega = \omega.$$

I would be thankfull for any answer and/or opinion wheather you expect this to be true or not.

**Remark (Edit)** If one replaces the tame condition by the condition of compatibility, the answer is yes. Any unitary trivialization with respect to the metric $g_t(\cdot,\cdot) := \omega(\cdot, J_t \cdot)$ would do the job. However, this argument seems not to carry over to the tamed case..

Comment: If $J_0$ is compatible with $\omega$, and if such $\Phi_t$ exists, then $J_t$ is compatible with $\omega$ for any $t$, so in general you cannot find such $\Phi_t$.

Comment: Thanks! I guess your right and such a trivialization does not exist..